# java changing a string that has alphabets in it to a double

Tags: java

I am reading a file that looks like

0.45643456778D-02 0.345533677477D+08 .....

thousands of numbers like this (literally) .... and I am reading them as a string, but I want to change them to double so that I can further use them using mathematical operations ... but I cant ..

the D means "raise-to" ... so how can I assign it to a double. I know (math.pow), but since its a loop that reads through these thousands of line, I cant manage to use it ...

```java
...
String iope = parts[j];
double af0 = new Double(iope.valueOf(iope));
System.out.println(iope);
...
```

with out the second line the output is fine, but with the second line it says,

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.45643456778D-02"

Comment: So `0.45643456778D-02` is `Math.pow(0.45643456778, -2)` then?

Comment: If your mantisa and exponent is separated by "D", then you can use split and parse separately mantisa, then use pow with exponent

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `0.45643456778D-02` means `Math.pow(0.45643456778, -2)`, you can do a `split` on `'D'`, then parse the two sides individually:

```
String iope = parts[j];
String[] token = iope.split("D");
double baseVal = Double.valueOf(token[0]);
double af0 = (token.length == 2)
?   Math.pow(baseVal, Double.valueOf(token[1]))
:   baseVal;
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/e7uDLE)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning BigDecimal here. Given the fact that we don't about the precision that the OP wants/has to achieve.

Comment: i am getting "cannot find symbol" on the "split"